# Integration testing with remote restful service

Tags: java, rest, integration-testing, cucumber-jvm

My task is to implement **integration tests** which have to use remote **restful service**. Thing is, that we don't want any test data **put** in real restful service.

In general we have:

Controller responsible for saving and loading data from RESTful:

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/user/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)    
    saveUserData(@RequestParam String data, @RequestParam String user){

        // here is the logic to send the data to save
        restfulClient.save(user, data);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/user/load", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    loadUserData(@RequestParam String data , @RequestParam String user){

        // here is the logic to load the data from restful service 
        return restfulClient.load(user, data);
    }
```

RestfulClient just makes put and get requests to remote restful service to save and load user data.

2 Cucumber scenario:

```
    When user User is saving data some_data
    Then user User sees saved data is some_data
```

3 Cucumber test:

```
@When("^user (.+) is saving data (.+)$")
public void whenSave(String userName, String data) throws Exception {
    MockHttpServletRequestBuilder req = post("/user/save").contentType(APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8).content(data);
    callUrl = getMockMvc().perform(req.session(userName));
}

@Then("^user (.+) sees saved data is (.+)$")
public void thenResponseAndDataAreCorrect(String userName, String data) throws Exception {
    MockHttpServletRequestBuilder req = get("/user/load").content(data);
    callUrl = getMockMvc().perform(req.session(req.session(userName));
    callUrl.andExpect(status().isOk());
    callUrl.andExpect(jsonPath("$.Records[*].data", hasItems(userName)));
}
```

Tests can be executed simultaneously in different threads so the user_id can be different for each test. In this case we need the possibility to write and to read the data for each id.

```
http://some.restful.service/{user_id}
```

Will be good to know some approach that we can use in case described above.

Comment: Well what you ask is trivial. Have you considered using `dbunit` (dbunit.sourceforge.neta)? By using it you can set a state for your db before running your tests and remove all test created data after your tests finish.

Comment: Is the remote RESTful service under your control at all? Can you make a copy of it for testing purposes to prevent any poisoning of a live environment? If not, you may want to look into mocking out this RESTful service (by creating your own simplified version of it), and running integration tests against that instead.

Comment: We chosen the approach to mock out the RESTful client.

Comment: I personally agree with your approach mocking. And I hope SoapUI can be helpful for you http://www.soapui.org/Getting-Started/mock-services.html

Answer (score 0):

What kind of software project management are you using? E.g. You can use maven and you could launch the integration test. Click here for more help: http://clearqa.blogspot.com.es/2013/04/fun-with-cucumber-jvm-bdd.html